Learning rate not updating
def make_prediction(x0,t0):
    inputs = torch.vstack([x0,t0])
    layer_1 = torch.matmul(w0,inputs)
    return layer_1

loss1 = nn.MSELoss()
def loss_function():
            u_t=(make_prediction(x,t+inf_s)-make_prediction(x,t))/inf_s
            u_x=(make_prediction(x+inf_s,t)-make_prediction(x,t))/inf_s
            u_xx=(make_prediction(x+inf_s,t)-2*make_prediction(x,t)+make_prediction(x-inf_s,t))/inf_s**2
            return (1/N_i)*(loss1(make_prediction(x0IC,t0IC), u0IC))+(1/N_b)*(loss1(make_prediction(x0BC1,t0BC1), u0BC1))
            +(1/N_b)*(loss1(make_prediction(x0BC2,t0BC2), u0BC2))+(1/N_f)*(np.pi/0.01)*(loss1(u_xx-u_t-make_prediction(x,t)*u_x, 0))

def train_step(w,b, learning_rate):
    trainable_variables = [w,b]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(trainable_variables, lr=learning_rate,momentum=0.9)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.01)
    loss = loss_function()
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        w -= learning_rate * w.grad
        b -= learning_rate * b.grad
        w.grad.zero_()
        b.grad.zero_()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
train_step(w,bias,learning_rate)

I run this code (by scheduler.ExponentialLR), but there is no change in the learning rate.
Where do you think the problem comes from?
I write the full code...thanks from your help

Your are hardcoding the weights and bias calculations. In this case, the optimizer cannot have access to that.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


def train_step(w, b, optimizer, scheduler, loss_function):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = loss_function()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    return loss.item()


def loss_function():
    rand_input = torch.randn(64, input_size)
    target = torch.randn(64, output_size)
    output = rand_input.mm(w) + b
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(output, target)
    return loss


input_size, output_size = 100, 3
learning_rate = 0.01
w = torch.randn(input_size, output_size, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.randn(output_size, requires_grad=True)
trainable_variables = [w, b]
optimizer = optim.SGD(trainable_variables, lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.99)
steps = 10000
display_step = 100


graph1 = []

for i in range(steps):
    loss = train_step(w, b, optimizer, scheduler, loss_function)
    if i % display_step == 0:
        graph1.append(loss)
        print(f'Epoch {i} \t Training Loss: {loss}')

graph = torch.tensor(graph1)



Prints
Epoch 0      Training Loss: 94.3976058959961
Epoch 100    Training Loss: 1.1436320543289185
Epoch 200    Training Loss: 1.1590440273284912
Epoch 300    Training Loss: 0.9118895530700684
Epoch 400    Training Loss: 0.8449723720550537
Epoch 500    Training Loss: 0.9973302483558655
Epoch 600    Training Loss: 0.9681441783905029
Epoch 700    Training Loss: 1.1692309379577637
Epoch 800    Training Loss: 1.0565043687820435
Epoch 900    Training Loss: 1.0424968004226685
Epoch 1000   Training Loss: 0.9199855923652649
Epoch 1100   Training Loss: 1.1443506479263306
Epoch 1200   Training Loss: 0.9741299748420715
Epoch 1300   Training Loss: 1.1515040397644043
Epoch 1400   Training Loss: 1.2819862365722656
Epoch 1500   Training Loss: 0.9993045926094055
Epoch 1600   Training Loss: 1.066098928451538
Epoch 1700   Training Loss: 1.0772987604141235
... 


